# Login with Eclipse team share with AccuRev

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse, accurev

It appears that I need to login to the AccuRev project depot each time I open my eclipse workspace when sharing projects with AccuRev.  Is this true?

My current setup is MyEclipse 10.7 with plugin for AccuRev 5.7.  When existing projects are already shared with AccuRev, every time I open up the workspace again..I have to login to each and every project shared with an AccuRev depot.  Sometimes I can select multiple projects and login just once but most times its for each project.

Is this the way its suppose to work or is it just buggy?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to log into AccuRev everytime you open a workspace.

Does this happen if you are not using Eclipse (just the AccuRev client)?

Are you running the latest AccuRev eclipse plugin?

Are you running on a supported Eclipse version?

http://www.accurev.com/accubridge-support-matrix.html

Comment: The accurev client is good.  I'm using MyEclipse 10.7 which is based off of Eclipse 3.7.  And the AccuRev plugin is 5.7 which came up earlier this year, just one version behind.  I believe that's the latest I can use, given my environment.

Do you have a working environment?  Which version of eclipse/accurev plugin do you have that works?  Thanks

Comment: I have the following environment and do not have the problems detailed above.  Eclipse version 4.3.1, AccuRev plugin version 2013.5, AccuRev client version 6.0.1.  I would try updating the AccuRev plugin if you are not currently using the 2013.5 version.